# how to generate a knowledge graph from a video clip

Tags: video, knowledge-graph

I have developed knowledge graph of CSV files but I am not able to develop  knowledge graph of an image or video clip. Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I mean how to generate a knowledge graph from a video?